# Getting number of duplicates before removing them

Tags: excel, vba

I just want to get the number of duplicates removed when using the .RemoveDuplicate function in excel vba. Is there anyway to get the precise number of how many duplicates are removed when using the excel function?

Code:

```
rangeofws.RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlYes
```

rangeofws is just a range variable that defines the used range of the worksheet. I look at the first column to check for duplicates as its the column that contains my Key which should supposedly be all unique, hence me wanting to remove any duplicates. I just need the number of duplicates before they are removed by the function.

Do I have to just find the number of rows before and after the removal then find the difference between the two?

Answer (score 0):

Do you need the number of duplicates **before** they get removed or is **after** removal ok too.

As you already found out, it is just counting rows before removal and counting them after removal.

```
Dim RowCountBefore As Long
RowCountBefore = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Worksheets("Sheet1").Columns("A"))

Dim RowCountAfter As Long
RowCountAfter = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Worksheets("Sheet1").Columns("A"))

Dim RowsRemoved As Long
RowsRemoved = RowCountBefore - RowCountAfter
```

Comment: Thanks. I did it slightly differently. Instead of using the `.CountA` function, I count the number of rows in my used range using `Worksheets("Sheet1").UsedRange.Rows.Count` and stored it in a variable just like how you did, once before the removal, and once after. Did a difference between the two variables and we should both have arrived to the same answer. Would there be any problem using `.UsedRange` to count the number of rows? Hopefully not.

Comment: @DSM yes `.UsedRange` is not very reliable and could count empty cells too. `CountA` will only count non empty cells.